# Angular Elements cannot bind value with curly brackets

Tags: angular, custom-element, angular-elements

I want to export Angular component as custom web component. My component has input:

```ts
@Input() inputFileID: string;
```

which is used to bind to properties in HTML:

```html
<input type="file" name="{{inputFileID}}" id="{{inputFileID}}" 
      (change)="onFileDrop($event)" class="filedrop__uploadtext" />
<label for="{{inputFileID}}" class="filedrop__uploadlabel"> Upload file </label>
```

Unfortunately `inputFileID` seems to be empty. I dropped this custom element in index.html like this:

```html
<custom-file-drop-element inputFileID="fileOne"></custom-file-drop-element>
```

and in inspect mode I see that this was rendered:

```html
<input type="file" class="filedrop__uploadtext" name="" id="">
<label class="filedrop__uploadlabel" for=""> Upload file </label></div>
```

Comment: Looks like your variable `fileOne` is null. Your code works fine in StackBlitz, see [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p6rgnm?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular Elements attributes need to be small case with dashes, instead of camel case. In this case, custom element should be something like this:

```html
<custom-file-drop-element input-file-id="fileOne"></custom-file-drop-element>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this in Ts

```
   @Input() inputFileID: string;
   fileId:any;

 ngOnInit() {
  if (this.inputFileID && this.inputFileID!=null) {
     this.fileId = this.inputFileID;
   }
}
```

in Html File

```
<label for="{{fileId}}" class="filedrop__uploadlabel"> Upload file </label>
```